# PJSUA/PJSIP - Unable to increase support to 32 accounts/transports/calls

Tags: python, build, voip, configure, pjsip

I've tried various attempts using config_site.h during build, and had little to no improvement... Still stuck at 8 accounts. Code is:

```
import pjsua

lib = pjsua.Lib()
lib.init()
lib.start()

transport = lib.create_transport(pjsua.TransportType.UDP)
for x in range(10):
    lib.create_account_for_transport(transport)
```

And:

```
Assertion failed: (pjsua_var.acc_cnt < (sizeof(pjsua_var.acc)/sizeof(pjsua_var.acc[0]))), function pjsua_acc_add, file ../src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_acc.c, line 401.
```

Comment: Found this thread and followed it, but doesn't seem to have changed anything. http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2013-February/015771.html

Comment: This link also has some information on what I'm trying to do, but is vague and attempting to follow the instructions still limits me to 8 accounts (Unlike the OP, who gets the error after 10 accounts). http://pjsip.pjsip.narkive.com/nffwBaTd/hundreds-of-accounts-with-pjsip-python-binding

Comment: Hey, what is the right procedure? I'm also stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems not only to be a PJSUA/PJSIP issue, but a platform specific issue (Mac OS X) as the (nearly) identical steps were performed on `Ubuntu 15.10` and it was able to create additional accounts with no issue.

Steps completed on working `Ubuntu 15.10` install:

```
sudo ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC CXXFLAGS=-fPIC
sudo make dep && make
sudo make
cd pjsip-apps/src/python
sudo make
sudo python setup.py install
```

Note: Issues during `make dep` (pjsip) and `sudo make` (python lib) required running `sudo make` and `sudo python setup.py install` again to properly complete install.

These same steps, completed on a `Mac OS X 10.11` platform, does not allow for additional transports nor additional accounts to be created. Will attempt a second question specifically addressing transports.