# How do I increase the max number of Transports in PJSUA?

Tags: python, c, build, config, pjsip

## Summary

I am trying to support 32 unique accounts with 32 unique IP:Port addresses. I am currently able to use `config_site.h` during build to adjust the max account (`PJSIP_MAX_ACC`) successfully, but the transports are still limited to the default 8.

**Aside from `PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES` and `PJSIP_MAX_TRANSPORTS`, what other settings are needed to allow for 32 total unique transports?**

***Extra Credit: What would the C equivalent of the below Test Code be, so I may test the library directly?***

## Historical

After [struggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403656/pjsua-pjsip-unable-to-increase-support-to-32-accounts-transports-calls) to understand how to build using config_site.h properly, I was able to finally see some results on a `Ubuntu 15.10` install. Unfortunately, while seeing some changes, I am unable to see the changes I need to accomplish my program;  32 transports with 32 accounts.

The references I used to attempt these changes were found via the [PJSIP Mailing List](http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2013-February/015721.html), [Narkive Mailing List Archive](http://pjsip.pjsip.narkive.com/nffwBaTd/hundreds-of-accounts-with-pjsip-python-binding), with minimal help from the [PJSIP Reference Documentation](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/1.16/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSIP__CONFIG.htm#gab97c3ae493d49efea6f41eb4b930c794) and [Getting Started Guide](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Build-Preparation).

The final result was a `config_site.h` with 8 different settings (see Code section below). Unfortunately it still doesn't get me where I'm trying to get.

I am needing unique IP:Port addresses due to the fact that I am attempting Peer-To-Peer VOIP calls, that are redirected through a forwarding/proxy server twice, causing account detection of the software to not work consistently.

## Code

### config_site.h

```
/*
 * This file is customized by Ash to (attempt) to override the 
 * default settings of PJSIP to support much more  
 */

#define PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES      32
#define FD_SETSIZE_SETABLE      1
#define __FD_SETSIZE            32

#define PJSIP_MAX_TRANSPORTS        32
#define PJSIP_MAX_RESOLVED_ADDRESSES    32

#define PJSUA_MAX_ACC           32
#define PJSUA_MAX_CALLS     32
#define PJSUA_MAX_PLAYERS       32
```

### Test Code (via Python)

```
import pjsua

lib = pjsua.Lib()
lib.init()
lib.start()

custom_range = 32
transport = dict()
acc = dict()

for x in range(custom_range):
    transport[x] = (lib.create_transport(pjsua.TransportType.UDP))
    print 'Transport', x, 'created:', transport[x]

for x in range(custom_range):
    acc[x] = (lib.create_account_for_transport(transport[x]))
    print 'Account', x, 'created:', acc[x]

print 'All Clear. Shutting Down.'

lib.destroy()
lib = None
```

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ashpesante/Documents/Development/PyCharms/pj/32t32a.py", line 12, in <module>
    transport[x] = (lib.create_transport(pjsua.TransportType.UDP))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pjsua.py", line 2302, in create_transport
    self._err_check("create_transport()", self, err)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pjsua.py", line 2721, in _err_check
    raise Error(op_name, obj, err_code, err_msg)
pjsua.Error: Object: Lib, operation=create_transport(), error=Too many objects of the specified type (PJ_ETOOMANY)
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'" in <bound method Lib.__del__ of <pjsua.Lib instance at 0x10c0f58c0>> ignored
```

### Undefine Error

```
_pjsua.c: In function ‘py_pjsua_enum_transports’:
_pjsua.c:1202:17: warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     pj_status_t status;
             ^
_pjsua.c: In function ‘py_pjsua_conf_get_port_info’:
_pjsua.c:2338:9: warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int status; 
     ^
_pjsua.c: In function ‘py_pjsua_get_snd_dev’:
_pjsua.c:2714:9: warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int status; 
     ^
```

Comment: Try unsetting FD_SETSIZE:
```#include <sys/types.h> <lf>
#undef __FD_SETSIZE <lf>
#define __FD_SETSIZE            32```... but you'll probably want it higher than 32. (Apologies for formatting, no line breaks in comments.)

Comment: I think you have something... I did see a bunch of undefining elsewhere but it never clicked... And yes you are correct, I'll likely be boosting all `32`'s to be `1024`. If I can end up with even close to that I'll be golden! Now, looking through the docs, it seems `FD_SETSIZE` = `__FD_SETSIZE`, should I undefine both prior to setting?

Comment: Hmm new error now but that's actually a good thing, because that means something changed! I ended up undefining both FD_SETSIZE and __FD_SETSIZE and defining them as I wanted. I will toy around with this tonight and update the question to reflect any results. So excited!

Comment: By the way, I was recently informed that pjsua Python bindings are being deprecated, and that the pjsua2 swig bindings will replace them (http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html#using-in-python-application).

Comment: After repeatedly testing the build, it seems that `#include <sys/types.h>` is causing an issue while building the `python` egg and .o file... As its the only difference between my 'psuedo-functional' `config_site.h` and the current one that's breaking the build. Also, I was playing with `pjsua2` a little but had complications during `swig` part so I dropped it, but if its the next step I'll have to look further.

Comment: Hit another wall... Saw an error I could fix by just a quick`recompile with -fPIC` and it seems to get rid of the error but there are still some errors... I'll add these to the question.These seem to happen regardless of if I include `sys/types.h` and possibly related to `#undefine __FD_SETSIZE`. Also, I was playing with pjsua2 a little but had complications during swig part so I dropped it, but if its the next step I'll have to look further.